# Speed up for loop by using sorted NSArray with ids

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, for-loop, nsarray

I have a foor loop that cycles through a quite large amount of objects (4000+ at the moment, but potentially the double and growing.
I'm try to speed up the cycles, I was able to free memory using autoreleasepool and avoid app crashes, but in terms of speed the cycle is quite slow.
Somebody suggested me to use ordered array, but I'm pretty new to programming so I'm a bit lost. Can anybody share some directions?

Objects in "Sede" have progressive IDs

This is my code:

```
NSArray *sedi = [Sede sedeArray];
for (Sede *sedeTmp in sedi)
        {
            @autoreleasepool {
                if (sedeTmp.idSede == idSede)
                {
                    sede = sedeTmp;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is my FULL code:

```
+ (void)importData:(NSDictionary *)data
{
    NSArray *info = data[@"Info"];
    if (info != (id)[NSNull null])
    {

    }

    NSMutableArray *utenti = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[Utente utenteArray]];
    NSMutableArray *utentiNew = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSDictionary *utenteWS in data[@"Utenti"])
    {
        NSInteger stato = [(NSNumber *)[NSString decrypt:utenteWS[@"Stato"]] integerValue];
        NSInteger idUtente = [(NSNumber *)[NSString decrypt:utenteWS[@"IDUtente"]] integerValue];
        Utente *utente = nil;
        for (Utente *utenteTmp in utenti)
        {
            if (utenteTmp.idUtente == idUtente)
            {
                utente = utenteTmp;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (stato == 2) //DELETE
        {
            if (utente)
        {
            [self setUtente:utente fromUtenteWS:utenteWS];
            utente.eliminato = YES;
        }
        continue;
    }
    if (!utente)
    {
        utente = [Utente utente:(int)idUtente];
        [utentiNew addObject:utente];
    }
    [self setUtente:utente fromUtenteWS:utenteWS];
}
[BOTManagedObjectContext save];

[utenti addObjectsFromArray:utentiNew];
NSArray *sedi = [Sede sedeArray];
NSMutableArray *sediDel = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *contattiDel = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *sedeWS in data[@"Sedi"])
{
    NSInteger statoSede = [(NSNumber *)[NSString decrypt:sedeWS[@"Stato"]] integerValue];
    long long idSede = [(NSNumber *)[NSString decrypt:sedeWS[@"IDSede"]] longLongValue];
    Sede *sede = nil;


    NSArray *sedeArray = [Sede sedeArray];
    NSMutableDictionary *itemsByItemID = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (Sede *sede in sedeArray) {
        itemsByItemID[@(sede.idSede)] = sede;
    }
    self.sedesBySedeID = itemsByItemID;



    //for loop is too slow
    /*for (Sede *sedeTmp in sedi)
    {
        @autoreleasepool {
            if (sedeTmp.idSede == idSede)
            {
                sede = sedeTmp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }*/
    //end of guilty for loop

    if (!sede)//if enters here, local db is empty
    {
        if (statoSede == 2) //DELETE
            continue;

        sede = [BOTManagedObjectContext insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Sede"];
        sede.idSede = idSede;
        NSInteger idUtente = [(NSNumber *)[NSString decrypt:sedeWS[@"IDUtente"]] integerValue];
        for (Utente *utente in utenti)
        {
            if (utente.idUtente == idUtente)
            {
                sede.utente = utente;
                break;
            }
        }
        for (NSDictionary *contattoWS in sedeWS[@"Contatti"])
        {
            if ([(NSNumber *)[NSString decrypt:contattoWS[@"Stato"]] integerValue] == 2) continue;

            Contatto *contatto = [BOTManagedObjectContext insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contatto"];
            contatto.sede = sede;
                [self setContatto:contatto fromContattoWS:contattoWS];
            }

            [self setSede:sede fromSedeWS:sedeWS];
        }
        else
        {
            if (statoSede == 2 && !sede.tour) //DELETE
            {

                [sediDel addObject:sede];
                for (Contatto *contatto in sede.contattoCollection)
                {
                    [contattiDel addObject:contatto];
                }
                continue;
            }

            for (NSDictionary *contattoWS in sedeWS[@"Contatti"])
            {
                NSInteger statoContatto = [(NSNumber *)[NSString decrypt:contattoWS[@"Stato"]] integerValue];
                BOOL find = NO;
                long long idContatto = [(NSNumber *)[NSString decrypt:contattoWS[@"IDContatto"]] longLongValue];
                for (Contatto *contatto in sede.contattoCollection)
                {
                    if (contatto.idContatto == idContatto)
                    {
                        find = YES;
                        if (statoContatto == 2) //DELETE
                        {
                            [contattiDel addObject:contatto];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            [self setContatto:contatto fromContattoWS:contattoWS];
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!find)
                {
                    if (statoContatto == 2) //DELETE
                        continue;

                    Contatto *contatto = [BOTManagedObjectContext insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contatto"];
                    contatto.sede = sede;
                    [self setContatto:contatto fromContattoWS:contattoWS];
                }
            }
            //controllo se ci sono contatti non presenti nel ws e in caso li elimino
            for (Contatto *contatto in sede.contattoCollection)
            {
                BOOL find = NO;
                for (NSDictionary *contattoWS in sedeWS[@"Contatti"])
                {
                    long long idContatto = [(NSNumber *)[NSString decrypt:contattoWS[@"IDContatto"]] longLongValue];
                    if (contatto.idContatto == idContatto)
                    {
                        find = YES;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!find)
                {
                    [contattiDel addObject:contatto];
                }
            }

            [self setSede:sede fromSedeWS:sedeWS];
            if (statoSede == 2 && sede.tour)
                sede.eliminata = YES;
        }
    }
    [BOTManagedObjectContext save];

    for (Contatto *contatto in contattiDel)
    {
        [BOTManagedObjectContext deleteObject:contatto];
    }
    [BOTManagedObjectContext save];

    for (Sede *sede in sediDel)
    {
        [BOTManagedObjectContext deleteObject:sede];
    }
    [BOTManagedObjectContext save];

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use an NSDictionary instead of an NSArray.

Answer (score 5):

The fastest way to perform *many* lookups is to convert your `NSArray` into an `NSDictionary`. This initial conversion will take linear time which is the same amount of time your current loop takes. *However*, future lookups will only take constant time!

```
NSArray *sedeArray = [Sede sedeArray];
NSMutableDictionary *itemsByItemID = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (Sede *sede in sedeArray) {
    itemsByItemID[@(sede.idSede)] = sede;
}
self.sedesBySedeID = itemsByItemID;
```

This method only takes constant time to find your object.

```
- (Sede *)sedeForSedeID:(int)sedeID {
    return self.sedesBySedeID[@(sedeID)];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. What kind of property is sedesBySedeID?

Comment: A property in your class. You need some way to hold on to the dictionary. What is a Sede?

Comment: Sede is ManagedObject that contain several NSString

Comment: @property (copy, nonatomic) NSDictionary *sedesBySedeID; then?

Comment: Copy or strong works depending on what you want. You should look up the difference if you don't know.

Comment: self.sedesBySedeID = itemsByItemID; gives 2 errors:

Comment: "Member reference type 'struct objc_class *' is a pointer" and "incomplete definition of type 'struct objc_class'"

Comment: Hard to tell what you are doing wrong without any code.

Comment: I just edited my question with full code I'm using. right in the middle there's the commented for loop I was using before. At the bottom of the page I have your method - (Sede *)sedeForSedeID:(int)sedeID { return self.sedesBySedeID[@(sedeID)]; } while in .h I have the proerty: @property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *sedesBySedeID;

Comment: You should put your original code back in addition to your new code. StackOverflow is designed to help future viewers of this question. Let them see what you started with.

Comment: The error is telling you that you are missing the pointer symbol `*` in your property declaration. NSDictionary is an object and your property is a _pointer_ to that object.

Comment: Sorry that was my typo here. I have it in the code but it still give those 2 errors: "Member reference type 'struct objc_class *' is a pointer; maybe you meant to use '->'?" and "Incomplete definition of type 'struct objc_class'"

Comment: The error is because the method you are in is a _class method_. This is designated with the `+` symbol. `self` refers to the instance of your class on which the method is being called, which isn't applicable here because it's not an instance method. Try using static storage instead. You may need to rethink how this class is working.

Answer (score 4):

The advantage of using a sorted array is that you can binary-search it, rather than linear-search it. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) has a pretty nice description of the algorithm.

To do that, you start in the middle, then, if you haven't found the value, check whether you're too high or too low, and jump halfway the opposite direction. Eventually, you'll either find the value, or "halfway" will be 0 steps and you know it doesn't exist.

Here's enough to get you started.

```
NSUInteger findInSortedArray(NSArray *arr, id obj) {
    NSUInteger low = 0;
    NSUInteger high = arr.count;
    while (low + 1 < high) {
        NSUInteger mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if ([arr[mid] isEqual:obj]) return mid;
        // ..
    }
    return -1;
}
```

(You can also find sorted collection libraries on the internet that will make this easier for you.)

If *all* you're doing is checking for membership, however, there's an even easier solution: use an `NSSet` instead of an `NSArray`, or an `NSDictionary` mapping each `id` to its object.

Comment: Thank you for making it more clear to me. However I'm not sure if I'm able to translate this in code. How should I proceed? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DavideC: I gave you half the code, and a link to a Wikipedia article that has the code written in C and also has links to other implementations. (Wikipedia also includes a secret shortcut that will make your life even easier, which I didn't want to give you until you understood what binary search was all about.) Try to write it yourself; if you get stuck, you can ask a specific question.

Comment: Thank you. My previous comment was about your post before edit.